# How to check matches pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to matches the pattern like `"sec 30-31"` . But its not working for me.

I am using matches pattern like below.

```
private boolean checkConstraint(String inputValue) {
    inputValue = inputValue.trim();
    if (inputValue.matches("[\\>][\\s]*[\\d]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\<][\\s]*[\\d]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\d]*[\\s]*[-][\\s]*[\\d]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\=][\\s]*[\\d]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\=][\\s]*[\\w]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\d]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\d]*[\\s]*[|][\\s]*[\\d]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[|][\\s]*[\\w]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\d]*[\\,][[\\s]*\\d\\,]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\,][[\\s]*\\w\\,]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\d]*[\\s]*[\\?]")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[\\?]") || inputValue.matches("[\\d]*[\\s]*[\\*]") || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[\\*]")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[\\w\\,]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\s]*[\\%]*[\\s]*[\\w]*[\\s]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\s]*[\\w]*[\\s]*[\\%][\\s]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\s]*[\\%]*[\\s]*[\\w]*[\\s]*[\\%][\\s]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[-][\\s]*[\\w]*") || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[.][\\s]*[\\w]*")
            || inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*['][\\s]*[\\w]*") || inputValue.matches("[[\\w]*[\\s]*[\\w]*[\\s]*]*")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I want to matches string "sec 30-31" it will return true when i  matches its return false `inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[-][\\s]*[\\w]*")`.

Anyone can help me please.

Thanks

Sitansu

Comment: Please give a clear example input and expected output.

Comment: Oh, this is ambiguous: `[[\\s]*\\d\\,]`. The inner brackets are ignored in Java regex.

Comment: Also, instead of `if(a) { return true; } else { return false; }`, you could simply `return a;`

Comment: @Sitansu: Do you need all those regexps? I doubt anyone is going to 
"decode" them for you. To match your expected string, you just need something like [`"[a-zA-Z]+\\s+\\d+-\\d+"`](https://ideone.com/0ObdhT).

Comment: Still unclear. Why 30-31? Should it match 80-81 too? And 1-2? And 99-00? Do the first 3 letters matter? Should the amount of letters be 3 exactly? As the question is currently written, the answer could be: `return inputValue.equals("sec 30-31");`

Comment: @GyroGearless: No, it will match an alphanumeric, it is Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex

```
inputValue.matches("[\\w]*[\\s]*[-][\\s]*[\\w]*")
```

Won't match `sec 30-31` because it matches `alphanumerics`+`whitespaces`+`-`+`whitespaces`+`alphanumerics`. As you see, no place for a number.

You need to add another `matches()` to your "pipeline":

```
inputValue.matches("[a-zA-Z]+\\s+\\d+-\\d+")
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0ObdhT) returning `true`.

Here,

- `[a-zA-Z]+` - matches 1 or more Latin letters
- `\\s+` - matches 1 or more whitespace
- `\\d+` - matches 1 or more digits
- `-` - matches a literal hyphen
- `\\d+` - matches 1 or more digits.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.